# Angular 2 current route to be shared on Linked In, Twitter, and Facebook

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Presently I've hard coded links such as the following:

Linked In:

```
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http%3A//www.beeps.com%3A7002/index.html&title=&summary=&source=" class="SHARE LINKED_IN" onclick='window.open(this.href,"popupwindow", "width=800,height=500,left=200,top=5,scrollbars,toolbar=0,resizable"); return false;' target="social"></a>
```

Twitter:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/home?status=http%3A//www.beeps.com%3A7002/index.html" class="SHARE TWITTER" onclick='window.open(this.href,"popupwindow", "width=800,height=500,left=200,top=5,scrollbars,toolbar=0,resizable"); return false;' target="social"></a>
```

Facebook:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A//www.beeps.com%3A7002/index.html" class="SHARE FACEBOOK" onclick='window.open(this.href,"popupwindow", "width=800,height=500,left=200,top=5,scrollbars,toolbar=0,resizable"); return false;' target="social"></a>
```

All of these links seem to work when referenced from Linked In, Twitter, or Facebook - but I want to create an Angular 2 that substitute the `&url=http%3A//www.beeps.com%3A7002/index.html` portion of the `<a>` element based upon the current Angular 2 route, so we don't have to hard code this for every page.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I ended up taking was to create a `route.watcher.service.ts` that populates a variable containing the current route URL - for each social media share that I needed to create I simply copied the route URL value from the `route.watcher.service.ts` using a component function that is data bound to the anchor `<a>` `href` attribute within the particular social media share component.

Route watcher service:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class RouteWatcherService {
    private routeUrl:string;

    constructor(private router:Router) {
        this.router.changes.subscribe(() => {
            this.routeUrl = this.router.serializeUrl(this.router.urlTree);
        });
    }

    url():string {
        return this.routeUrl;
    }
}
```

Twitter share component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {RouteWatcherService} from '../route.watcher.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'twitter-component',
    templateUrl: 'twitter.component.html'
})

export class TwitterComponent {
    constructor(private routeWatcher:RouteWatcherService) {}

    routeHref() {
        return window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + this.routeWatcher.url();
    }
}
```

Twitter share component `HTML` template:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/home?status={{routeHref()}}" class="SHARE TWITTER" onclick='window.open(this.href,"popupwindow", "width=800,height=500,left=200,top=5,scrollbars,toolbar=0,resizable"); return false;' target="social"></a>
```